# Github error using Jekyll. A file was included in `/_layouts/default.html` that is a symlink or does not exist in your `_includes` directory

Tags: github

They say file is not there, but it simply is.

[image: snapshot]

I created `default.html` in `_includes` and it worked fine.

I created `navigation.html` in the same directory exactly as tutorials said.

It errors when I try to put `{% include navigation.html %}` in as an include in `default.html`.

Tried absolute link too.

No other page will even upload until I delete the `{% include navigation.html %}` line from `default.html`.

I cannot understand why it says it is not there as it certainly is. What am I missing?

default.html:

```html
    <!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{ page.title }}</title>
  </head>
  <body> 
{% include navigation.html %}
    {{ content }}
  </body>
</html>
```

content of navigation:

```html
<nav>
 test (putting url here makes no difference, nor does having a blank page)
</nav>
```

Originally just tried this:

```html
<nav>
  <a href="/">Home</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Why do you say your files are in `_includes` directory but your screenshot shows them in `_layouts` directory ? There would be no problem if the `navigation.html` really was in `_includes`. So were is it really ?

Comment: After hours as a newbee I couldn't see the forest for the trees. Thanks for pointing out what I was obviously missing, like I had said...LOL. Sorry I wasted your time on such a silly mistake, but I appreciate you pointing it out.